# test unreachable execution path within golang function

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm writing unit-tests to cover all execution paths in the fabric chaincode below. But I don't see a way to reach the JSON.Marshall failing path.

How can I pass a value that passes to `json.Unmarshal` but it fails to `json.Marshal`?

```golang
func (c *MyContract) CreateAsset(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, values string) (bool, error) {
    
    doctype := "myAsset"
    txData := []byte(values)
    docData := new(DocData)
    docData.DataType = doctype

    // validate json input & map to struct
    err := json.Unmarshal(txData, &docData)
    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("failed docData unmarshalling: %s", err.Error())
    }

    docKey, _ := createKey(ctx, doctype, []string{docData.Key1, docData.Key2})

    exists, err := c.DocExists(ctx, docKey)
    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("could not read from world state %s", err)
    } else if exists {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("asset already exists")
    }

    txBytes, err := json.Marshal(docData)
    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("failed docData bytes marshalling: %s", err.Error())
    }

    return true, ctx.GetStub().PutState(docKey, txBytes)
}
```

This is my current test:

```golang
func TestCreateAsset(t *testing.T) {
    var err error
    ctx, _ := setupStub()
    c := new(MyContract)


    _, err = c.CreateAsset(ctx, "{")
    assert.EqualError(t, err, "failed unmarshalling: unexpected end of JSON input", "testing malformed json")

    _, err = c.CreateAsset(ctx, "{\"key1\":\"mis\",\"key2\":\"sing\"}")
    assert.EqualError(t, err, "could not read from world state some failure")

    _, err = c.CreateAsset(ctx, "{\"key1\":\"001\",\"key2\":\"002\"}")
    assert.EqualError(t, err, "asset already exists")

}
```

Comment: `json.Marshal` is only going to error if you pass it an invalid value to marshal. If `DocData` is valid, that it is not going to fail.

Comment: Also, consider the repercussions of adding _additional_ error vectors in your code solely to test for errors which should not happen to get a better coverage number. Presumably whatever consumes the output of that function is already testing its `false, error` path.

Comment: @JimB I totally get your point. In that regard, it would be safe to omit capturing error from `json.Marshal` since it would've been tested by then, right?

Comment: IMHO I would leave the error check even if it's very unlikely, since the next person to read the code will expect it, and it's no harder to write the error check than a comment explaining why the error is handled differently. If you didn't want to return the error, then the next correct thing to do would be to panic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `json.Marshal` function fails when a value in the data cannot be marshaled.  The only way to induce a failure is to introduce a field for testing and slip in a bad value during a test:

```
type DocData struct {
    …
    Test       interface{} `json:"test,omitempty"`
}

…

var induceFailure interface{}

…

docData.Test = induceFailure
txBytes, err := json.Marshal(docData)
if err != nil {
    return false, fmt.Errorf("failed docData bytes marshalling: %s", err.Error())
}

…

func TestMarshlFail(t *testing.T) {
    induceFailure = make(chan struct{})
    defer func() {
       induceFailure= nil
    }()
    …
```

It's probably not worth the hassle to get the test coverage on that line of code.

Unrelated to the question at hand, here are some improvements for your code.

- Wrap errors instead of converting the errors to strings:

  ```
  return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed docData unmarshalling: %w", err)
  ```
- Because `docData` is a pointer, there's no need to take the address of the value when unmarshaling.

  ```
  err := json.Unmarshal(txData, docData)
  ```